# Connecting to PostGreSQL from PHP Server extension in VS Code

Tags: php, postgresql, windows, vscode-extensions

Alright, so I have the VSCode PHP Server extension, by brapifra, installed on a windows machine.  I am able to do most PHP code just fine by serving the PHP pages.  Now I am trying to connect to a PostGreSQL database using pg_connect().   Please note that I DO NOT have apache installed as I was trying to use the VSCode server extension instead.

When I installed PHP on the machine, I setup an environment variable to the PHP folder so VSCode can access it directly.

When I try to serve a PHP page using pg_connect(), or similar, functions, I get a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()" error.

Is it possible to run PHP through VSCode with extensions only and NOT having to install Apache?

When I installed PHP on my machine, it had a php.ini-development file which I renamed to php.ini and took the ; off the appropriate lines
`extension=pdo_pgsql ;extension=pdo_sqlite extension=pgsql`
but I still get the "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()" error.

Comment: please note, that I am able to run PHP just fine, it only fails when using postgresql connection functions.  So those libraries are not being loaded or accessed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you are able to help me here, you do not need any more code!